# Full height video - drop content after right below browser window

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen, viewport

I'm trying to achieve same functionality with video as seen here: http://www.bootply.com/108614

Video should take whole browser window size and when user scroll down he sees other content immediately. Obviously you cant place video as CSS background and use calc height so need to find another solution.

Any help with the solution?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yes I did try with multiple different ways. Now I found a solution how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to achieve this by using javascript to calculate viewport height.

HTML

```
<div class="head">
 <div class="video-content">
  <video autoplay loop poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
   <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
 here is content
</div>
```

CSS

```
.welcome {
 height: 100%;
}
.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: yellow;
}
video#bgvid { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
 -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.head').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

[Working example in JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kcbhex7m/)